# Display New Badge Woocommerce If In New Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I need to display a 'new' badge to product on the archive page but only for products in the 'New' category

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'lottie_new_badge', 40 );

function lottie_new_badge($badge) {
global $product;

if (has_term ('new')) {
    echo '<p>New</p>';
}
return $badge;
}
```

Got this code but not working, mixed few bits of code together to try get it to work but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing arguments when using `has_term()` function with Woocommerce product category. Also as you are using an action hook, `$badge` is not needed and not has to be returned like in a filter hook. So try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_lottie_new_badge', 40 );
function display_lottie_new_badge() {
    global $product;

    if ( has_term ( array('new'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        echo '<p class="new">New</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.